# A simple python code about if

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, double, range

Under python 2

```
    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(i):print i,j

    for i in range(6):
        for j in range(i):
            if j:print i,j
```

I notice the difference of those two results but I still don't understand what does if j mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(i):
        if j:print i,j
```

The above if statements makes sure that i and j are not printed when the value of j is zero.
Most datatypes have intrinsic boolean property in Python. for numbers any non-zero values translates to True while zero translates to False

Answer (score 1):

Python Documentation on truth testing:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Specifically:

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition. The following values are considered false:
>
> zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0
>
> All other values are considered true

`if j:` will trigger when j is non-zero and do nothing when `j` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what happened in `if i:`, try this.

```
for i in range(-6,6):
    if i:
        print "%2d is evaluated as True"%i
    else:
        print "%2d is evaluated as False"%i
```

output:

```
-6 is evaluated as True
-5 is evaluated as True
-4 is evaluated as True
-3 is evaluated as True
-2 is evaluated as True
-1 is evaluated as True
 0 is evaluated as False    <----- Just "if 0:" is evaluated as "if False:"
 1 is evaluated as True
 2 is evaluated as True
 3 is evaluated as True
 4 is evaluated as True
 5 is evaluated as True
```

Answer (score 0):

It checks if j is True. Numerical value of 0 is interpreted as False and every other as True.

Answer (score 0):

The second loop is conditioning on j, if j is not false, i.e if j <> 0 so it just prints the values where j is not equal to 0